# XML parsing in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I need to parse the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataList Name="DistributorList">
   <Distributor Id="Select" Name="Select">
      <Town Id="Select" Name="Select">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
   </Distributor>
   <Distributor Id="107" Name="Royal Motors">
      <Town Id="Select" Name="Select">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
      <Town Id="21" Name="Gurgaon">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
   </Distributor>
   <Distributor Id="109" Name="ALI DISTRIBUTOR POINT">
      <Town Id="Select" Name="Select">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
      <Town Id="21" Name="Gurgaon">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
   </Distributor>
   <Distributor Id="144" Name="Goyal Accessories">
      <Town Id="Select" Name="Select">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
      <Town Id="22" Name="Faridabad">
         <Beat Id="Select" Name="Select">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
         </Beat>
         <Beat Id="1" Name="Area1">
            <Dealer Id="Select" Name="Select" />
            <Dealer Id="24964" Name="Kanhaiya Dial " />
            <Dealer Id="24964" Name="Kanhaiya Dial " />
            <Dealer Id="24965" Name="B.K.Mobile Service Centre" />
            <Dealer Id="24965" Name="B.K.Mobile Service Centre" />
            <Dealer Id="24966" Name="Narayan Telecom" />
            <Dealer Id="24966" Name="Narayan Telecom" />
            <Dealer Id="24967" Name="Pawan Telecom" />
            <Dealer Id="24967" Name="Pawan Telecom" />
            <Dealer Id="24968" Name="Sri Ram Communication" />
            <Dealer Id="24968" Name="Sri Ram Communication" />
         </Beat>
      </Town>
   </Distributor>
</DataList>
```

I have no clue on how to do it.

I used the below code but it is not getting the element name

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(temp);
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("DataList");

// looping through all item nodes <item>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    Log.e("Distributor Id=", parser.getValue(e,"Distributor Id"));
    Log.e("Name=",parser.getValue(e,"Name") );
    Log.e("Town Id=",parser.getValue(e,"Town Id" ));
    Log.e("Name=",parser.getValue(e,"Name" ));
}
```

Comment: An element `<Distributor Id="Select" Name="Select">` has "Distributor" as the element name and "Id" is an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML pull parser does my help exactly what I need.

[XML PULL PARSER](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html)